# behavior at boundary of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, summation, power-series

I have a rather general question and would be happy if you could teach me how to answer it :-)

Consider for example $$f(x)=(1-x)^{1/3}$$ which one could represent as a power series: $$(1-x)^{1/3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n-1/3)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(-1/3)}x^n.$$ For $g(x)=\frac1{f(x)}$ we have $$(1-x)^{-1/3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/3)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(1/3)}x^n.$$

Now say we define 
\begin{align}
F_N&=\sum_0^N\frac{\Gamma(n-1/3)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(-1/3)}\\
G_N&=\sum_0^N\frac{\Gamma(n+1/3)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(1/3)}.
\end{align} 
Clearly $F_N\to0$ and $G_N\to \infty$. And one could also show that $G_NF_N \to \frac{3\sqrt3}{2\pi}\neq 1$.

**Question**
How can I in general analyze $F_NG_N$ when $F_N$ and $G_N$ are partial sums of the coefficients of the power series of two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where $f(x)=\frac1{g(x)}$ and that $g(x)$ diverges when $x\to  1$?

I appreciate any help and/or reference :-)